# How do I put a code block in a comment that starts and ends with spaces?

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting, markdown

I was writing a reply in a comment just recently and I realized I could not turn something into a code block if it started and ended with a space.  The particular comment in question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904466/regex-to-extract-2nd-and-3rd-string#comment113006338_63904466).  After a little trial and error, I have come to the following conclusions:

- In comments, the backticks are just rendered as literal backticks.  They do not turn into a code block.  [image: Comment with backticks]
- In both questions and answers, the spaces are trimmed and it is rendered as a code block, but just as if the spaces were not there.  [image: Question without spaces]
- In both questions and answers, you can work around this problem using <code> tags, but in comments, these also render literally.  [image: Comment with code tags]

Are there any workarounds for comments?  Can this be fixed?  If anyone is wondering why this is important, I was writing a regex string in which the spaces were a critical part of the regex.  The match needed to start and end with a literal space.  So yes, there is a real need for this.

Comment: Testing: ` code here`. Yup, doesn't work. Pretty sure Markdown doesn't even support that.

Comment: `​ test ​` Looks like you can work around it by adding a zero-width space next to the backtick, not sure if that might cause any copy-paste problems though.

Comment: testing `​ test `

Comment: Note that in most cases for regex you should use \s for spaces anyway... so it can be the solution for this particular scenario

Comment: @JohnMontgomery That works!  Displays correctly, and the zero-width space does not copy.  Seems like a hacky workaround, SO should really fix the rendering system, but I think that's the best answer there is for now.  You should post that as an answer here.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I disagree, `\s` matches any whitespace, including spaces, tabs, and newlines.  A literal space is more specific, and in this case, the OP was clear that they only wanted to use space as a delimiter.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery How did you add that?

Comment: @Scratte An easy way is to google "zero width space", find the first and best site, and copy it from there. Lots of sites have a copy field. A generally safe one should be [\u200b](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm), which you can also get by running `copy("\u200b")` in the console. Gonna sanity-check real quick: `​ test ​` - yep, 200b works

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong `"\x20test\x20"` should work in that case...

Comment: I don't see why you need this functionality. Just wrap your regex in quotes or brackets or something.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That works, but a literal space makes it shorter.  I'm not against using other workarounds,  I just think I should be able to format my original regex as code, as I'm sure someone on SO will probably run into this same issue at some point in the future.

Comment: @TylerH I suppose the last sentence on my question was an overstatement.  I don't "need" this, I just think it would be nice and would make the comment look cleaner.  As you can see in the comment I posted, I just left the backticks in there, and I think everyone on SO knows what backticks are supposed to mean.  It's more of a "why not?" thing.

Comment: "The particular comment in question is on this question (7th comment down, posted by me)." - It would probably be easier to just link to the comment itself - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63904466/regex-to-extract-2nd-and-3rd-string#comment113006338_63904466

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 I didn't know you could do that, that's cool!  I've updated the question.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Since regex has to be entered, it may itself be wrapped into something, not necessarily code block. E.g. in C# regex expressions are strings, so `" (.+) (.+) "` is natural.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is apparently [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79254/recent-change-of-inline-code-in-comments-leads-to-mistakes-in-old-comments/79344#comment193706_79344) that leading/trailing spaces aren't allowed in inline code, though I can't find any reference for why this is.

As a workaround, you can add a zero-width space character (U+200B) next to the backtick on either side, which will not trigger the problematic behavior:

```
`(U+200B) test (U+200B)`
```

becomes `​ test ​`. This works both in comments and in questions/answers.

(See [this Super User post](https://superuser.com/questions/156640/how-can-i-type-u200b-character) for how to add the character)

However, copying the code apparently may cause the zero-width characters to also get copied in some circumstances, so it's probably best to avoid needing to do this in the first place if you can.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery I agree on the trolling thing; this clearly isn't trolling at all. However, Alexei's concern about the invisible character *is* real; it may not be visible to you when you paste it (that's kind of the point of an *invisible* character) but it *will* be copied/pasted when someone tries to copy code and paste it into their IDE. And then they will get a warning about invalid characters when validating or compiling, etc.

Comment: @TylerH I did the same length test Alexei did and got 6, is what I mean. And the browser console shows invisible characters, which it didn't show in the copied string.

Comment: @TylerH In this case the zero-width space is not copied when selecting and using CTRL+C because it is at the beginning of the string, and it is zero-width, so it is impossible to select.  I've tried, and the only way I can get that zero-width space into my clipboard is if I make my selection start at the character prior to the code block, which I don't think people would do.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I think you underestimate how much effort people put into selecting from the right point when they copy code from Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: @TylerH LOL, maybe that's true, but I don't think we can be held responsible for other people's sloppiness.  They could also select the space character after the code block, not notice it, and end up with an issue there.  I think we have to assume people who truly want to solve a problem will take some care when implementing a proposed solution.

Comment: Also note that the zero-width space is only required at the beginning, not the end.  So just `\`(U+200B) test \`` will work.

Comment: Since SO has migrated to CommonMark... we can refer to CommonMark's discussion now :) specifically, [Leading and trailing white spaces in code blocks](https://talk.commonmark.org/t/leading-and-trailing-white-spaces-in-code-blocks/628/21). Note that [SO is now using markdig](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) that "*strip all leading and trailing spaces inside backtick spans and collapse internal runs of spaces (i.e. behavior currently specified by Commonmark)*"

Answer (score 4):

I don’t always write regex answers on meta, but here I am. You can put the spaces in character classes:

```
[ ](.+) (.+)[ ]
```

While it’s more verbose, it can be copied and pasted without being confusing or secretly messing people up (as seems likely with Unicode weirdness).

This isn’t a solution that would fix the problem if it occurs with other technologies, but often good communication is a good workaround too. For example, say how many spaces go before a line of code if you’re in a language where that matters and it’s not obvious.